# Matlab coder for "spline" function

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

Using the built in function of MATLAB coder, which converts matlab to c++, is it possible to convert internal matlab functions like spline?  I follow the directions from http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/11/14/generating-c-code-from-your-matlab-algorithms/  but I get errors on variables from even the beginning when trying convert the spline function.  Has anyone had success with this.  I imagine matlab would need to convert ppval, mkpp, unmkpp etc...

Specifically speaking, almost every line gives me an error, with the first line:

```
[x,y,sizey,endslopes] = chckxy(x,y);
```

giving the error

```
  Undefined function or variable 'chckxy'.
```

But when i do "edit chckxy" matlab says it doesnt exist, so im not sure how to get around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a subset of functions are currently [supported](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html) with MATLAB Coder. In your case, it seems like the function `chckxy` does not exist in MATLAB or it is an internal function (private or MEX file).

Comment: so that means its impossible to convert anything that does interpolation? or is there a way around this

Comment: There are limited options with `interp` and `interp2` which are supported with MATLAB Coder.